# Order of an element with a non-negative power

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory

Question: If $a$ has order $15$, write down a non-negative power $m$ such that $a^{m}$=$a^{-1}$ and also find all $m$ such that $a^{m}$=$a^{-1}$ 
Here is what I have that might relate to the question being asked of me
Does there exists $k$ such that order $a^{k}$=$d$$?$
order of $a^{k}$=$\frac{n}{(n,k)}$ if $0\lt k \lt d$
suppose the order is $15$
 then $a^{k}$=$\frac{15}{(15,k)}$=$d$ where $\frac{d}{15}$ 
$15$=$d(15,k)$
$\frac{15}{d}$=$(15,k)$ 
so $d$=$3$ 
then $5$=$(15,k)$ so $k$=$5$
Here is the notes that I have but but I can not seem to solve the question being asked of me. Need help

Comment: Try multiplying both sides of the equation $a^m = a^{-1}$ by $a$.

Comment: but I need a nonnegative power for my first question

Comment: So? How is that relevant?

Comment: how what is relevant?

Comment: If we are talking about elementary group theory here, your notes show that you don't understand what is being asked at all. Please talk to your teacher/professor/TA about it: they are there to help you understand.

Comment: @Nick I dont have nothing in my notes that is similar to this question. I was using the notes I put up to see if Its close to answering it. I take it that my notes are useless for this question

Comment: Are you talking about elementary group theory? Do you know what the order of an element of the group is?

Comment: You are thinking too hard. $a^{-1} $ is the *unique* element so that $a*a^{-1}=e $. And $a $ has order 15 means $a^{15}=e $. So $a^{15}=e=a*a^{-1) $ so.... what is $a^{-1} $.

Comment: yes. Order of an element of a group: Let $G$ be a group and $a\in G$. Then $a$ is said to have finite order if there exists $n\ge 1$ such that $a^{n}$=$e$

Comment: @fleablood tour translation is confusing me

Comment: Hint: $a^{15}=e $.  So $a^{m}a^{15-m}=e $.  So $a^{1}*????=e $.

Comment: @fleablood would it be $a^{14}$? I am taking it as you let $m$=$1$

Comment: Seriously?  I'm confusing you?  Look you know $a*a {-1}= e $.  $a^{15}=e $.  And $a^m=a^{-1} $.  Put them all together $e=a^{-1}=a*a^m=a^{15} $.   It's... not a trick question.

Comment: @fleablood: you are confusing him because your LaTeX is not well formatted. You are missing \$ delimiters.

Comment: Of course it is 14.  $a*a^{14}=a^{15}=e$.  So $a^{14} $ is the multiplicative inverse of $as.  It's that simple.

Comment: Am i.  I'm on my phone and Latex is not formated in comets so I can't see if I make a LaTex typo.

Comment: Try again:  $a^{-1} $ is the *unique* element so that $a*a^{-1}=e $. And $a $ has order 15 means $a^{15}=e $. So $a^{15}=e=a*a^{-1} $ so.... what is $a^{-1} $.... ah, I had a ")" instead of "}".  Hopefully it's fixed.

Comment: Autocorrect, is not helpful with latex, either.

Comment: So if $a^{15}=e $ then what is $a^{16} $, $a^{17} $?  What is $a^{23} $? $a^{314} $ So what *else* is equal to $a^{-1}=a^{14} $?

Comment: is it infinite since $a$ has no finite number for finding all $m$  such that  $a^{m}$=$a^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a$ has order $15$, it means that $a$ has $15$ different powers:
$$1,a,a^2,a^3,\dots,a^{13},a^{14}$$
and that $a^{15}=1$.

From this, we have 
 $\ a^{15k+d}=\overbrace{a^{15}\cdot \ldots \cdot a^{15}}^{k\text{ times}}\cdot a^d=a^d$ for all integers $k,d$.

In particular, $a^{15k-1}=a^{-1}$, and these are exactly the integer exponents that result in $a^{-1}$. 
We get nonnegative exponents for the values $k\ge0$. The first such exponent is $14$, and indeed:
$$a\cdot a^{14}=a^{14}\cdot a=a^{15}=1$$
so $a^{14}$ is an inverse of $a$.